# customize step in loop through pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, generator, yield

I know this question was asked a few times, but I couldn't understand the answers or apply them to my case.

I'm trying to iterate over a dataframe, and for each row, if column A has 1 add one to the counter, if it has 0 don't count the line in the counter (but don't skip it).
When we reach 10 for the counter, take all the rows and put them in an array and restart the counter. After searching a bit, it seems that generators could do the trick but I have a bit of trouble with them. So far I have something like this thanks to the help of SO community !

```
data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,50,size=(50, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
data['C'] = np.random.randint(2, size=50)
data

counter = 0
chunk = 10
arrays = []
for x in range(0, len(data), chunk):
    array = data.iloc[x: x+chunk]
    arrays.append(array)
    print(array)
```

the idea looks something like this :

```
while counter <= 10:
    if data['A'] == 1:
        counter += 1
        yield counter
    if counter > 10:
        counter = 0
```

But I don't know how to combine this pseudo code with my current for loop.

Comment: Could you add an example of the desired output?

Comment: The desired output is the same as the current output you'd get if you execute the first bit of code (up to print(arrays)) but instead of having 5 arrays of 1 rows each, you have for example : let's say the first 15 rows have 10 1's and 5 0's in column A. That whole chunk is the first array, and we start to count for the new array on the next line. Once we have passed through 10 rows where A = 1, we take all the rows in between and put them in the second array and so on. I don't know how to do that so I can't show you visually what it would look like sorry

Answer (score 1):

When we use `pandas`, we should try not do for loop, based on your question , we can use `groupby`

```
arrays=[frame for _,frame in data.groupby(data.A.eq(1).cumsum().sub(1)//10)]
```

Explain :

we do `cumsum` with A if it is 1, then we will add the number up, 0 will keep same sum as pervious row, and `//` here is get the div to split the dataframe by step of 10 , for example 10//10 will return 1 and 20//10 will return 2.

Comment: Hi @YOBEN_S thanks for the answer. I put pandas as an example to simplify but I actually use another library called vaex, very similar to pandas but for larger dataframes (100 Million rows +). It has almost the same caracteristics, but it does not have those functions like cumsum or groupby, that's why I want to use a for loop

Comment: I tried converting the whole dataframe to numpy and use cumsum but my computer can't take it all into memory.